# compare values using regex sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Does anyone knows how to say if val1 = X/state/Amercia/LA/ or X/state/ the val2 = 'LA'.

**code**

```
 when TRIM(val1) like '^X*/state/' or TRIM(val1) like '^X*/LA/' then 'LA'
```

Thank you

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, a *clear* explanation, and a database tag.

Comment: The `like` operator does not accept any regular expression, but requires a PostgreSQL dialect. You can look it up [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-like/). Your best option is the [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html) on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Given these results (please note I preserved the spelling of 'Amercia'):

```
select trim('X/state/Amercia/LA/') ~ '^X/state/($|Amercia/LA/$)';
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)

select trim('X/state/Amercia/LA/') ~ '^X/state/($|Amercia/LA/$)';
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)

select trim('X/state/') ~ '^X/state/($|Amercia/LA/$)';
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)

select trim('X/state/SomethingElse') ~ '^X/state/($|Amercia/LA/$)';
 ?column?
----------
 f
(1 row)

select trim('Xother') ~ '^X/state/($|Amercia/LA/$)';
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)

select trim('X/state/Amercia/VA') ~ '^X/state/($|Amercia/LA/$)';
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

Your `when` should be:

```
  when trim(val1) ~ '^X/state/($|Amercia/LA/$)' then 'LA'
```